# Specflow+ Xunit Running every case twice in visual studio

Tags: nunit, xunit, specflow, visual-studio-2022

I am using specflow with xunit and i am facing the issue as if i right click and run one selenium test case from the test explorer, all the other test cases also runs and both run twice.
i have installed the following dependencies:

```
<PackageReference Include="Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus" Version="7.5.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="DotNetSeleniumExtras.WaitHelpers" Version="3.11.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk" Version="17.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.TestPlatform.TestHost" Version="17.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="MongoDB.Driver" Version="2.14.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Selenium.WebDriver" Version="4.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Selenium.WebDriver.ChromeDriver" Version="96.0.4664.4500" />
    <PackageReference Include="SpecFlow.Plus.LivingDocPlugin" Version="3.9.57" />
    <PackageReference Include="FluentAssertions" Version="6.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="SpecFlow.Tools.MsBuild.Generation" Version="3.9.40" />
    <PackageReference Include="SpecFlow.xUnit" Version="3.9.40" />
    <PackageReference Include="xunit" Version="2.4.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="xunit.assert" Version="2.4.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="xunit.runner.visualstudio" Version="2.4.3">
```

i have tried removing packages folder from users/nuget folder and build again but that also did not helped..
However i did not faced this problem with Nunit

Comment: It sounds like you have duplicate *.feature.cs files. Remove the duplicates.

Comment: i have two feature files but i am using chrome driver in only one feature file and the other has only backend test cases

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

SpecFlow.Plus.LivingDocPlugin is a plugin for Specflow not Xunit. If you need to use both Specflow plus and Xunit you should also include the main Specflow libraries needed to interface with Xunit.

```
SpecFlow
SpecFlow.xUnit
SpecFlow.Tools.MsBuild.Generation
```